# What's your CV 'hit-rate' on careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs, fun

Just for fun and to see how unemployable I am:

My CV 'hit-rate' on careers is currently a glorious **`0.01484%`** (yea, uh, `Search Hits on Your CV` / `Global Searches`, just in case you have not finished your morning cup-a-joe.)

Within my hits my CV 'view-rate' is **`0.0667%`**. (`Employer Views of Your CV` / `Search Hits on Your CV`)

So if my skill set not in demand (at least with the beta employers)? Or my locations to in-the-middle-of-nowhere?

What's your hit-rate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think any of the beta testers were in Singapore, and the site has only been open to non-beta testers for a couple of days, so it's probably a function of location in your case. I hope that as we hit critical mass we'll start to attract employers all over the world.

Comment: Yea, relocation's a b**** in the current economy.  I don't think I've ever seen a Singapore based job on the job boards at joelonsoftware, or stackoverflow.  :-/

Answer (score 16):

Mines a big fat...

### **0**

:) But then again I'm in Australia (for better or for worse). But considering the jobs on SO and Joels are predominantly North American, this isn't that surprising. I only signed up because it was $30. If it was the normal price and I was a user outside the US, I don't think you could justify the cost.

Comment: I think your close enough to me that we are in the same boat.

Comment: if you know of Australian companies that would be a good match to Careers, email their contact info to careers@stackoverflow.com and parhaps we can entice them with a coupon?

Comment: @beggs: maybe we can get together and form a tele-commuting anarcho-syndacist commune dedicated to publishing fake climate data (through the latest Web 2.0 technologies).

Comment: *Help, help, I'm being repressed!* (Who elected *you* king then?

Comment: Come and see the violence inherent in the system!

Comment: There's some lovely filth on meta!

Comment: We could go on ...

Comment: Looking at these numbers Im guessing the 3 search hits I got were a user error. no wonder papa smurf has been slow to reply to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31285/can-we-see-the-count-of-relevant-employers-on-our-careers-page

Comment: @pavium/cletus/Adam Davis... please do go on.  I can up-vote Monty Python till the animator drops dead.

Answer (score 5):

Careers, I suspect, is going to hit its stride in 3-5 years as good programmers who use SO move into management.  Until then it's likely to be a bit slow and limited to the high-tech, early adopter areas - unless Joel and Jeff do a bang-up job of advertising the service to existing managers.  It's going to be a hard sell though, given that with many recruitment services you don't pay unless you hire.  Here you pay regardless of hire, and despite the money back guarantee that's a bump in the road.

Comment: I think the real hard sell is going to be convincing employers that it's worth their time to seek out excellent candidates instead of expecting excellent candidates to come to them. Especially with the current unemployment numbers.

Comment: True, but I suspect that those companies that do go out of their way to look for truly great programmers will expend the extra effort and cost, which is a win for good programmers.  It does mean a limited set of employers, but then do we really want the lukewarm employers anyway?

Answer (score 4):

I've got 11 hits, 2 employer views of my CV with global searches at 1015, so I'm near 1% of global searches, and 2.4% of the employers have seen my CV (assuming it wasn't the same one looking at it twice).  Which is 18% view rate (views/hits).

But I'm in Michigan, listed as "will relocate" and "telecommute" so I doubt anyone local is hitting me, especially given the current economy in this region.

But the economy and industry will certainly change over the next few years, even in Australia and other places where ponies and waffles are underappreciated.  Great employee/employer matches will come through this system, no doubt.

Or, in other words, the false positives will be much lower.  If you get contacted then it's a better match than through many (most?) other methods.  You won't get contacted much, but when you do it's a good contact.

Comment: I listed "will relocate" and I have the right to work in the US, but I don't suppose too many companies are looking to do long distance relocation at the moment.  It's an employers market.

Answer (score 2):

As of this morning:

```
1027 Global Searches
84 Search Hits on Your CV
8 Employer Views of Your CV
--------
8.17% Search Hits (Search Hit / Global Searches)
9.52% Employer View (Search Hit / Employer View)
```

Comment: Yeah, but you're awesome, which is so unfair to the rest of us plebes.

Answer (score 1):

3 Search Hits on Your CV :(

Answer (score 0):

My stats are

> 109 Global Employers (beta)
>   1106 Global Searches
>   63 Search Hits on Your CV
>   13 Public Views of Your CV
>   10 Employer Views of Your CV
>   2 Email Inquiries to You from Employers
>   2 Email Responses from You to Employers

Comment: Woot!  Inquiry!  But do you now have a new job?  Maybe there should be a bounty for the first user to get a job via careers...

Comment: I actually got another inquery yesterday. No new job just yet. Unfortunately the location was just a little far out for me.

Comment: I just updated my stats, the revision history here will be interesting to see.

Answer (score 0):

Hit-rate (Search Hits / Global Searches) = 4.39%

View-rate (Employer Views / Search Hits) = 8.51%

Actually kind of makes me feel better about my rates after calculating the percentages!

Answer (score 0):

I'm in pretty much the same boat as cletus (and country (without the pretty much)). I do have 1 Search hit however, but I have Willing to Relocate checked.

```
105    Global Employers (beta)
1077   Global Searches
1      Search Hits on Your CV
7      Public Views of Your CV
0      Employer Views of Your CV
0      Email Inquiries to You from Employers
0      Email Responses from You to Employers
```

Answer (score 0):

> 108 Global Employers (beta)
>   1106 Global Searches
>   17 Search Hits on Your CV
>   4 Public Views of Your CV
>   1 Employer Views of Your CV
>   0 Email Inquiries to You from Employers
>   0 Email Responses from You to Employers

My guess is the Public Views are either mine or from my SO profile.