# How about some Statistics for Public CV views?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I gave my public CV link to one person and I have 15 views, so I am a little curious to see some more detail about those views. Was it all from the same person, were some of them google?

I think it might also be useful to be able to append something to the querystring so I can give unique urls to everyone I send it to. Maybe something like

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/bob?1
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/bob?2

Is anyone else as curious as I am?

Answer (score 3):

Might as well just let us put in our google analytics ID and run google analytics on each of our pages.

Comment: If that could be added that would actually be pretty useful.

Comment: It's not going to happen, though.  They already run Google Analytics on all their pages, and I expect you can't run it twice.  Even if they could, it would a possible point of attack for hackers which would require extreme input validation since it's placed inside javascript code.

Answer (score 2):

You can always approach it in reverse: instead of handling out your full public CV URL, use one from one of the URL-shortening sites, and then look at their statistics to see how often it was used.  For example, http://3.ly/ makes that pretty easy.

Comment: this is a good idea. We do now provide "disposable" URLs on your publish tab, but we don't track stats. an URL shortening site that tracks stats would be the easiest way

Comment: +1, this idea is indeed slick and straight forward !!

Answer (score 0):

I'd be curious... but, I *know* the 1 public view I have is [by Joel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31649/whats-your-cv-hit-rate-on-careers/31651#31651)... And I don't think he will hire me.

Answer (score 0):

I know Jeff was talking on a podcast last month or so about really giving us a lot of stats but I still don't see any on my filed cv.  am I missing it somewhere?